# How to reference property set in service by APP_INITIALIZER after bootstrap

Tags: angular

In my Angular 8 application, I want to get a list of organizations from an API call before the app loads.  I am using APP_INITIALIZER to do so.  However, when the application is finished loading, a property for a selected organization on the service is no longer set as expected.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OrganizationsService } from './services/organizations.service';

export function orgResolverFactory(provider: OrganizationsService) {
  return () => provider.setOrgs();
}

providers: [ SidenavService, OrganizationsService, { provide: 
  APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: orgResolverFactory, deps: 
  [OrganizationsService], multi: true }
]
```

**organizations.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class OrganizationsService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
 orgs: any = [];
 selectedOrg: any;

 setOrgs() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get<Org>(`/api/orgs`,{ observe: 'response' })
        .subscribe(resp => {
          this.selectedOrg = resp.body[0]
          // breakpoint here shows this.selectedOrg is set
          resolve(true);
        });
      })
  }

  public getSelectedOrg() {
    return this.selectedOrg;
  }

}
```

**metrics.service.ts**

```
import { Org, OrganizationsService } from './organizations.service';

@Injectable()
export class MetricService {
  selectedOrg: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private organizationsService: 
  OrganizationsService) {
    this.selectedOrg = this.organizationsService.getSelectedOrg();
    // breakpoint shows this.selectedOrg is undefined
  }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to why selectedOrg in OrganizationsService is undefined after the app loads.  I want to be able to reference selectedOrg in the metrics service for further API calls.  How can I set this parameter before the app loads and reference it thereafter?  Is this even the right approach?

Comment: Does the first API call `/api/orgs` suceeded? whats the response data in it?

Comment: Yes, `/api/orgs/` returns successfully on first call.  It returns an array of objects, and selectOrg is properly assigned to first index.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to switch from using a service to a generic provider.  This allowed me to set and retrieve the property as desired.  In the case of my above code, services are generally instantiated at run-time.  Even though I was using my service before initialization, it was being reset when the app loaded.  Wanted to post this here answer in case others are looking to do something similar and have a similar problem.

**org-provider.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class OrgsProvider {

    private selectedOrg: any = null;
    private orgs: any = null;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    }

    public getSelectedOrg() {
        return this.selectedOrg;
    }

    public getOrgs() {
        return this.orgs;
    }

    loadOrgs() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get(`/api/orgs`,{ observe: 'response' })
          .subscribe(resp => {
            this.orgs = resp.body
            this.selectedOrg = resp.body[0]
            resolve(true);
          });
        })
    }

    setSelectedOrg(id:number){
      this.selectedOrg = this.orgs.find((org)=>{
        return org.id == id
      })
      return this.selectedOrg
    }

}
```